# Doob's Optional stopping time Theorem

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

There is a version of Doob's Optional stopping time theorem, which is stated as:

Let T be a stopping time. Let $X$ be a martingale. Then $X_T$ is integrable and $$E[X_T]=E[X_0]$$ if X is bounded and T is a.s. finite.

**Question:** Why do we need to require $T$ is a.s. finite? As $X_n$ is bounded, it will converge against some $X_{\infty}$. And we know that $X_{T\land n}$ is a martingale and use dominated convergence theorem and the fact $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_{T\land n}=X_T$, one can proof the claim. Which argument would fail to work if $T$ can be infinite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subset  $A=\bigcup_{n\geq 1} \{T= n\}$ should have full measure in the probability space. The sequence $X_{T\wedge n}$ converges pointwise on $A$ only. You will never attain the subset on which $T=+\infty$.

Comment: Could you explain bit more why I will never attain the subset on which $T=+\infty$?

Comment: I mean the set $\{T=+\infty\}$ is in the union given by A isn't it?

Comment: No, the sets $\{T=n\}$, $n\in{\Bbb N}$ and $\{T=+\infty\}$ are all disjoint. And by definition: $E(X_T) = \sum_{n\geq 1} E(X_n \; 1_{T=n})$ (using that $\{T=n\}$ is $X_n$-measurable. There is a priori no random variable $X_\infty$ in a Martingale sequence

Comment: But the random variable $X_{\infty}$ does exist and one can define it, isn't it? Then, $X_{T \land n}$ would also converge to $X_\infty$ in the case $T=\infty$ That is my question.

Comment: Ok, I get your point. You may do so, but there is a payoff in the condition of convergence. You may look at condition (c) on the wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem
and the remark just below the corresponding statement. Typically, this is really not what you want in applications.

Comment: Thanks! Helpful comments

Comment: You are welcome. In the applications I know of, the stopping time is designed so that you have some 'nice' property and it is important then that the stopping time has a finite expectation (which is part of Doobs when $T<+\infty$ a.e.). But, of course, this is not the issue of your question.